# Do que se trata o tipo numérico builtins?

Tags: python

Li no livro [Python para Desenvolvedores: Aborda Python 3.3](https://novatec.com.br/livros/python-para-desenvolvedores/) o seguinte trecho:

> Além do tipo numérico *builtins* do interpretador, na biblioteca
>   padrão do Python existem vários módulos dedicados a implementar outros
>   tipos e operações matemáticas.

Do que se trata esse tipo numérico *builtins*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Built-in são as bibliotecas embutidas do Python, você pode ver todas as existentes na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html)

As bibliotecas padrões podem ser usadas sem a instalação de nenhum módulo externo. Como por exemplo, para usar expressões regulares em python você pode usar o módulo re:

`import re`

Nada externo a linguagem foi instalado, mas o módulo está presente.

Transcrevendo builtin pode-se chegar em 'embutido'. Então são bibliotecas/módulos embutidos na própria linguagem.

Answer (score 1):

Trata-se de um atentado ao idioma português. Mas talvez seja um atentado culposo, pois pode ser desconhecimento linguístico do autor.

[*Built-in*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/built-in) é uma expressão em inglês que geralmente é traduzida como "embutido(a)". Significa que algo sobre o que você fala é montado ou construído dentro de outra coisa maior. Por exemplo, um armário embutido em uma parede, ou a direção hidráulica de um carro.

Na computação é comum encontrar outra grafia, *builtin*, que tem o mesmo significado. Nesse caso, também pode ser traduzido como "embarcado", "entregue", "disponibilizado" etc. a depender do contexto.

O que o Luiz Eduardo Borges quis dizer com o trecho na pergunta é que existe um tipo numérico que é embarcado/entregue junto com o Python - esse tipo faz parte da implementação do Python. Logo, se você tem o interpretador do Python instalado, você já pode usar esse tipo sem precisar baixar mais nada.

Existem módulos a parte que introduzem novos tipos e operações matemáticas que não fazem parte do Python. Para trabalhar com esses tipos, você precisa usar bibliotecas que não são embarcadas/entregues junto com o Python, e por isso esses tipos não são *builtin*.

TL;DR: esse trecho da [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type):

> a built-in type is a data type for which the programming language provides built-in support

Em uma tradução bem livre:
"Um tipo embarcado é um tipo de dados para o qual a linguagem de programação tem suporte sem precisar de mais nada".